# Entity Framework - Execute As USER Using linq

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity

I have a database with random privileges and for different  tables / views i have to execute command : `REVERT; EXECUTE AS User = '{0}'`.

Can someone tell me how it would look like in entity framework using linq.
Any idea?

I tried something like below but it is ok only for one request!

```
  public static mydbEntities Create(string user)
        {

 var context = new mydbEntities ();
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            objectContext.Connection.Open();
            var executeAs = string.Format("REVERT; EXECUTE AS User = '{0}';", user);
            objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(executeAs);


            return context;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!